# Why does cell text float outside my table?

Tags: tables

I find that the following code makes the indicated text float around outside of the table. Why is this?

Note that the code uses a custom cls file (companyname_sop); however, the same problem occurs if you use the article class file too.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{companyname_sop} %This is a custom cls file that applies formatting to the doc
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\title{Name of Doc}
\doctype{Name of Doc Type}
\docnumber{12-34567}
\supercedes{None}
\effectivedate{09/26/16}
\revisiondate{09/26/16}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{4cm}|p{.25cm}|p{.25cm}|p{11.5cm}|}
\caption{Title of Table} \label{t:label_of_table}
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c} {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- Continued from Previous Page }} \\ \hline 
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{Continued on Next Page} \\ \hline
\endfoot
\hline \hline
\endlastfoot 
\hline \fancyhead{}
\multirow{6}{\linewidth}{A line in the first column, which is meant to cover seven rows in the fourth column}  & \multirow{6}{\linewidth}{A} & 1 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 2 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 3 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 4 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 5 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}                   &                   & 6 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
 &  & 7 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages; however, it only shows when it's long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long in the penultimate row, so that only one row of the next section of the table shows up on the same page as the preceding rows           \\    \hline
\multirow{8}{\linewidth}{Line one of this line \newline Second line of this line}  & \multirow{8}{\linewidth}{B} & 1 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 2 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 3 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 4 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 5 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 6 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages
 \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 7 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 8 & A line \\ \hline
\multirow{8}{\linewidth}{This floats outside the table cells, at the level of the footer}  & \multirow{8}{\linewidth}{This does too} & 1 & A line \\* \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 2 & A line \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 3 & A line \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 4 & A line \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                   & 5 & A line \\ \cline{3-4}                 
                   &                   & 6 & A line \\ \cline{2-4}
                   &                   & 7 & Another line \\ \cline{2-4}
                   &                   & 8 & Another line again \\ \hline
                   & D &  & Yet another line \\ \hline

\end{longtable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item *Here is a footnote.
\end{tablenotes}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Apologies for the lack of line breaks; when I try to insert them in the code above for clarity, StackExchange seems to double the number of lines I want to add & box some of them (but not others) with grey highlighting, so it detracts from the clarity more than it adds to it.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the `companyname_sop.cls` file so that we can compile the file? Also, to format as code you select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the edit window.

Comment: it would be best if you could check you can get the same problem with `article` class and if so use that to save people downloading your custom class. If the problem only occurs with the custom class that is useful information to help someone debug

Comment: if you must use `\multirow` in longtable (it is best to avoid it) then you need to use `\\*` not `\\ ` to end the rows otherwise you may get a page break in teh rows that are being spanned.

Comment: Thanks folks; I tried adding * to the row breaks (I use //, not \\ as in the comment, to end rows, so I made it //*; let me know if this makes a difference), but it still doesn't work; I have posted the code for the cls file. Thanks for the notes.

Comment: `//*` would just typeset `//*` you need `\\*` to end a row

Comment: I just tried your docment and the only thing I see wrong is that "this does too" is too wide to fit  in column 2's .25cm column.   The text "This floats outside..." seems correctly typeset in teh first column

Comment: Oh sorry, David Carlisle, I have that backwards: I do use \\ in the table, not //; not sure why I mixed it up with // in the followup comment above, but that was incorrect. I do use \\ (or in this case, I've changed them to \\\*, but that hasn't worked).

I tried changing all four of the columns to |c| instead of |p{.25cm}| or the like, but I still have the text floating around outside the table. :/

Comment: Note that there is a great deal more script than just "A line," e.g., in the cells (I removed the actual text, for proprietary information concerns), so if it isn't pushing out of the table in your builds, that might be why

Comment: @andrew you don't have to guess what "my builds" look like as I just ran exactly the document that you posted. If the document you posted does not show the problem you are asking about then that's not really an example of anything and I suggest that you edit the question to fix the example.

Comment: OK David, please forgive me. The problem might not have been showing in the version above because it didn't have enough text in it to push the text off of the table. I have edited it. In the version above, what should be in the left-hand column is pushing almost off of the table, so that it's in line with the "Continued on Next Page" line; it shouldn't be down that far.

In the real version (before I stripped the content that has proprietary information in it), it goes even further, until it's in line with the footer, completely outside the lines of the table.

Comment: David Carlisle, I have also tried this with article class, per your suggestion, and it still returns the same problem. When the page break occurs, the text in the merged left-hand column (which is meant to span several rows of the right-hand column) floats around outside of the bottom of the table borders, in line with the page number.

Answer (score 2):

see, if the following code is useful to you. in it i change column widths so, that the table fit to text width and that cells' contents has enough space:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{makecell}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\makegapedcells
    \begin{longtable}{| p{\dimexpr4.0cm-1.25\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                        p{\dimexpr1.0cm-1.25\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                        p{\dimexpr0.5cm-1.25\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|
                        p{\dimexpr11.5cm-1.25\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|}
\caption{Title of Table}
\label{t:label_of_table}                    \\
    \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{-- Continued from Previous Page}   \\
    \hline
\endhead
    \hline
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on Next Page}}
\endfoot
    \hline
\endlastfoot
\multirow[t]{6}{=}{A line in the first column, which is meant to cover seven rows in the fourth column}
    & \multirow[t]{6}{=}{A} & 1 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 2 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 3 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 4 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 5 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 6 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &  & 7 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages; however, it only shows when it's long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long, long in the penultimate row, so that only one row of the next section of the table shows up on the same page as the preceding rows                               \\
    \hline
    \newpage
\multirow[t]{8}{=}{Line one of this line \newline Second line of this line}
    & \multirow[t]{8}{=}{B} & 1 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 2 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\*
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 3 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 4 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 5 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 6 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 7 & A much longer line than before, which forces the document to break over multiple pages, showing the problem, which is that the text in the first column floats outside the table when the table breaks over multiple pages \\
    \cline{3-4}
    &   & 8 & A line \\
    \hline
\multirow[t]{8}{\linewidth}{This floats outside the table cells, at the level of the footer}
    & \multirow[t]{8}{\linewidth}{This does too} & 1 & A line \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & 2 & A line        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & 3 & A line        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & 4 & A line        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & 5 & A line        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & 6 & A line        \\ \cline{3-4}
    &   & 7 & Another line  \\ \cline{2-4}
    &   & 8 & Another line  \\ \cline{2-4}
    & D & 9 & Yet another line  \\ \cline{2-4}
\end{longtable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item *Here is a footnote.
\end{tablenotes}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

it contain manual tweaking of page break.

Comment: Wow--well done, Zarko! That seems to have done it. Thanks for the wizardry!